# Visual Studio 2008 hangs selecting pending changes tab

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, ankhsvn

The project is using the ankhsvn plugin.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be great.  i already have the visual studio sp1 installed.

Also, ankhsvn is the latest version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does your project use unc (\\server\share) style paths?

If yes, can you check if using a daily build (http://ankhsvn.net/daily) fixes your issue?